# Bitdefender Antivirus Free: how to disable the web protection part in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bitdefender

I have the free version of Bitdefender. How can I disable only the web protection part?

I use Google Chrome under Windows 7.

Bitdefender isn't among the Google Chrome extensions.

In the free version of this software it looks like there isn't web settings.

Comment: @RiccardoLaMarca - I find it hard to believe that Bitdefender is able to scan encrypted traffic without installing a root certificate on your system.  I also find it hard to believe this is being done without some sort of add-on within Chrome.  Are you sure the problem is BItdefender?  Based on the experience of CaldeiraG, the free version of BItdefender, should not even have any web protection capabilities.

Comment: Yes, because the blocked pages (easily unlockable) there is the BitDefender header. I not have the screenshot because i have uninstalled Bitdefender for now.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

The free edition of Bitdefender does not have as full a suite of settings as you'll find in the paid for versions.

I pay for Bitdefender and enjoy the product.

But frankly, if you're going for free Anti-virus product, just use the Microsoft Security Essentials.

Answer (score 0):

From the article
[How to disable all modules in Bitdefender 2020](https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/28557/):

- Bring up the Bitdefender interface and access *Protection*
- In the ONLINE THREAT PREVENTION module, click *Settings*
- In the Web Protection tab, switch to OFF the protections you don't need
- You might perhaps want in the Network threat prevention tab, to set the switch to OFF
- Click SAVE to save the changes and close the window

As the free edition of Bitdefender does not have these settings,
I suggest installing the full trial version, disable
the ONLINE THREAT PREVENTION module, then let it degrade to the free version.
As I don't use Bitdefender, I cannot guarantee that this trick will work,
although it worked for me with other products.

Comment: This is a functionality in the paid version, not free, as @music2myear explained above.